# How can I pass a function as a prop to a React component using react-router <Redirect />?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props

I am trying to pass a function as a prop to a React component using react-router `<Redirect />` but as I understand it, you can only pass *serialized* strings, seeing as the router makes use of the history API.

Is there any way I can do this?

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

<Redirect
  to={{
    pathname: '/mypath',
    state: {
      something: 'else',
      myFunction: setPosts
    }
  }}
/>
```

**/mypath**

```
props.location.state.something
> 'else'
```

```
props.location.state.myFunction
> undefined
```

Comment: Please show the full component where you pass the function and where that function really is

Comment: @Vencovsky The function I am trying to pass lives in the same component that is doing the redirect. Is there something specific you would be looking for? The redirect is successful and the state is passed successfully, except when the prop is a function.

Comment: you dont need `this.` in your example above if that is what you have in your code. That should fix it.

Comment: @Rikin Good catch but it still doesn't work.

Comment: `console.log(props.location.state)` can you console log your state and see if its there what you are expecting, there may be a typo in accessing it

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Object to the state and function as the prototype of that object like below

```
const myFunction = Object.create({
   checkStatus: function(){
      console.log('function running');
   }
})
```

This will be added the function as the prototype of that object as shown below

[image]

> Now you can call the function as `props.myFunction.checkStatus()`.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot really see the function as being undefined as you suggest it is in the OP, when you use the `Redirect` component which has a function as part of it's state object, the target component will receive the state over `this.props.location.state` or `props.location.state` (depending on Container Component or Functional Component)

As a sample, I wrote the following, where a "long lasting calculation" is executed. Once you click on the link, it will jump to the new path, set a half a second timeout, and then redirect to the original homepage.

When the homepage doesn't detect a state, it will ask you to click the link, otherwise it will display the result

```js
const { Component, useEffect, useState } = React;
const { HashRouter: Router, Route, Redirect, Link } = ReactRouterDOM;

const GenerateResult = ( { location } ) => {
  const [ isCalculating, setCalculating ] = useState(false);
  const generateResult = function () { return 42; };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isCalculating) {
      const clear = setTimeout(function() {
        setCalculating( true );
      }, 500 );
      return () => clearTimeout( clear );      
    }
  }, [isCalculating]);
  if (!isCalculating) {
    return <div>Calculating, please wait</div>;
  }
  return <Redirect to={ {
    pathName: '/', 
    state: { from: location.path, result: generateResult }
    } } />
};

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    const { location } = this.props;
    const { state } = location;
    if (!state) {
      return <div>Click generate to get the answer to everything</div>;
    }
    return <div>{ `The answer to everything is ${state.result()}` }</div>;
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <h1>Your app</h1>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/long-lasting-process" component={GenerateResult} />
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/long-lasting-process">Click to run long lasting process</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.querySelector('#container') );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/5.0.1/react-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/5.0.1/react-router-dom.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```